# The lwip porting or window TCP/IP stack bug?

Tags: sockets, networking, wireshark, tcp

I am porting lwip stack to an embedded system...i write an application to send and receive data to window PC (using VNC protocol). However after sending a while, the PC netwrkd stack stop sending ACK...I could not see any problem from the Wireshark capture...it just tell the PC stop respond, I check the application on PC...it still wait on the read socket function. Could the Window Network stack has bug?

I attached the wireshark capture here (please look at from packet 4879...The PC IP is 192.168.2.43 and device IP is 192.168.2.214). Please help to take a look and advice.

Thanks

The image capture of wireshark here  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEckf.jpg
The wireshark file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn6lpieyzp4ornq/vnc_capture_winsock_error.rar?dl=0

Comment: Could the Window Network stack has bug?  A new, undetected bug that is so serious that it stops the comms completely, remaining hidden until connected to your peer despite the billions of other installations globally?  Guess what Mr. Occam has to say about that?  Anyway, down/close voting for the imgur links that make the question off-topic.

Comment: Well, i have been developed the lwip network stack for years and face a lot of problem but i can always find the root cause ..only this case, i could not have any clue...so just hope any expert can help to point out the problem

Answer (score -1):

Well, i got the confirmation from one expert in another forum. He confirm he has experience it before.It may due to the network device driver on the PC. Update the network device driver or enable TCP Offload Engine (TOE) will help

Comment: You got confirmation from what expert in what forum about what Windows stack bug? Without all that information this is merely hearsay.